# How do I get a scheduled action to fire on legacy records that already meet the decision block criteria?

Tags: process-builder, email-alert, scheduled-job, schedule

I have a process that sends scheduled emails (for example 30 days after record creation). The process works fine when I create a new record that meets the criteria. I can see the scheduled action in the paused interviews for the new record.

Now the problem is that I have many legacy records that meets the criteria. Is there any way to schedule the action to fire on legacy records that meets the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to edit the records so they no longer meet the criteria, then again so they do. This is traditionally done with the Apex Data Loader or a Batchable Apex script.